# How to rotate a dynamic array to the right?

Tags: c++, rotation

I have a custom array object. It has two main variables:

m_array = Pointer to dynamic array.

m_size - The size of the array. The size for this array is 10.

When I rotate to the left, this works fine:

```
 std::rotate(m_array + 0, m_array + 1, m_array + m_size);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
// simple rotation to the left
std::rotate(v.begin(), v.begin() + 1, v.end());
```

When I try rotating to the right, I'm getting a runtime error.

I need the equivalent of this:

```
// simple rotation to the right
std::rotate(v.rbegin(), v.rbegin() + 1, v.rend());
```

I tried this:

```
std::rotate(m_array + m_size, m_array + m_size + 1, m_array + 0);
```

I get the error: Invalid iterator range

So, I thought this was m_size, so I tried this:

```
std::rotate(m_array + m_size - 1, m_array + (m_size - 1) + 1, m_array + 0);
```

And I get the same error.

Thoughts are welcomed.

The source I tried to follow:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do a right rotation (to borrow your phrase), you want the range to be everything *but* the last element in the array.  I'll leave it to you to adapt this code to work on variable-sized arrays.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int data[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
                     5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    auto print_all = [&data]() {
        for(auto v: data) {
            std::cout << v << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    };
    print_all();

    // rotate elements to the left
    std::rotate(data, data + 1, data + 10);
    print_all();

    // rotate element to the right, back to the original position
    std::rotate(data, data + 9, data + 10);
    print_all();
    return 0;
}
```

My output looks like this:

```
./rotate 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: If it helps, just think about a right rotation as being a left rotation with the majority of the array (this is how I think about it).

Answer (score 4):

The reason `std::rotate(v.rbegin(), v.rbegin() + 1, v.rend())` works is that it uses reverse iterators.  That means that `v.rbegin() + 1` is actually decrementing the position in the array and is equal to `v.begin() + v.size() - 1`.

When using raw pointer arithmetic, there is no way to get the same reverse iterating behavior.  You will have to manually translate the left rotation to a right rotation.  This can easily be done by flipping the rotate position about the center of the array and performing a left rotate.

Left or right rotation can be boiled down to dividing an array into 2 sections and then swapping them.  Whether it is a left rotation or right rotation just dictates where the division is made.  For a left rotate by `k`, the rotation point is at `k mod N`.  For a right rotate, the rotation point is at `-k mod N` where `N` is the total length of the array.  This selects the index in the original array you would like to be at index `0` of the newly rotated array.

So the following right rotate by 1,

```
std::rotate(v.rbegin(), v.rbegin() + 1, v.rend())
```

is equivalent to using raw pointers in the following way:

```
int* p = &v[0];
int n = v.size();
int k = -1;
std::rotate(p, p + mod(k, n), p + n);
```

where `mod()` is the modulo operation (basically the `%` operator that always wraps to a positive number):

```
int mod(int x, int y) { return ((x % y) + y) % y; }
```

Answer (score 0):

````
void rotateRight(int arr[], int size, int p) {
    p = p % size; 
    int end = size - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        int temp = arr[end];
        for (int j = end; j > 0; j--) {
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];}
        arr[0] = temp; }} ```
````